# "Would" & " Used to"

Tags: word-usage, differences, modal-verbs

"Would " & " Used to ". 
They both are used for repeated action in the past tense. Then what is the difference between them?

Comment: I don't know whether there is any difference between them.  For this usage, *would* sounds slightly old-fashioned to me; my feeling is that *used to* is replacing it in AmE.

Comment: The difference is that *would* is used today to form the *conditional* form.

Comment: *They both are used for repeated action in the past tense.*  But what about, say, " there used to be a river running before my house"? I don't think it means any repeated action. Rather, I think "used to" here emphasises on the difference between the past and present. I'd not say " there *would* be a river running before my house", in which "would" indicates repeated action in the past, and that's certainly not what I'm intending to express.

Comment: I think the term "habits in the past" describes the use of  "my grandmother would always say/ used to say..." better than repeated actions in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Used to'and'would' are modals; though both apply to habitual action of the past,'would' carries with it a sense•• had it been so it might have been such••examples of which are there in UNCLE PODGER's absurdities. As regards use of the two,you're your best judge. Ask yourself--does it sound fine?

Answer (score 2):

I think the term "habits in the past" describes the use of  "my grandmother would always say/ used to say..." better than repeated actions in the past. I think one can say "used to do" is clearer and preferred today, whereas "would do" has the patina of older and more literary language.  I think "used to do" is preferred as "would" has already various uses.