# "Would" for past events

Tags: would

Is there any emotion implied (either positive or negative) when we use "would" for repeated past actions and situations? A few examples:

1. I would dream away on nights like this.
2. When a child, I loved it when my Grandpa dressed up as Santa Claus on Christmas Eve, and then I would be happy for hours.
3. When I was at school, the local bullies would beat me every day after classes.

The use of "would" seems rather "special" to me, so I often avoid it and use "used to" instead.

Thank you!

Comment: Related [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254185/would-used-to). Please take a look if it suits your question. If not, please edit your question focusing on what you don't understand from the previous question.

Comment: Would in the past simply indicates a habitual activity or something that was regularly done.  No emotions.  "I would wake up at 6am and get ready for school."  No emotions, just stating a fact.  Same as "used to."